# Opencv mask remove black background

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image that needs to be masked. This is result with css mask-image property

[image]

I need the same result in python opencv.

```
        alpha = cv2.imread(mask.getBGPath())
        image = cv2.imread(self.getBGPath())
        background = cv2.imread('cache/' + self.uuid + '/trans.png')

        image = image.astype(float)
        background = background.astype(float)
        alpha = alpha.astype(float)/255

        image = cv2.multiply(alpha, image)
        background = cv2.multiply(1 - alpha, background)

        outImage = cv2.add(background, image)
        
        cv2.imwrite(self.getBGPath(), outImage)
```

Alpha is mask image, background is transparent image.
Result is image with black background instead of transparent
[image]

How to remove this black backgroudn and make it transparent without losing quiality?

Comment: cv2.imread without any any flags loads RGB images not RGBA. Use flag cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED.

Comment: I have tried to do that, but I need to convert the other 2 images from RGB to RGBA which results in significant loss of quality

Comment: Conversion from RGB to RGBA doesn't result in quality loss. This conversion just adds additional channel and doesn't modify initial data.

Comment: Add input images (image,mask and background), so I will be able to give you a working example.